# Async Await JSON parse not awaiting

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, async-await

I'm having a problem with `async/await` not waiting for the previous statement. I'm trying to read a JSON file and then trying to manipulate the resulting object. 
The array is still undefined while it's doing the next functions despite having an `await`.

```
function initJson(file) {
  let obj;
  fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  try {
    const obj = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(obj);
   }
   catch (err) {
     throw err;
   }
 });
 return obj;
};

filterItemForKeyValue = function filterItemForKeyValue(obj, k, v) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'undefined' && obj) {
    return obj.filter(item => item[k] !== v);
  }
  return false;
};

async function handleFavorites(file) {
  let favorites = await initJson(file);
  favorites = await filterItemForKeyValue(favorites, 'delete', true);
  // here it's already false because favorites is undefined because it didn't wait

  console.log(favorites);
  return favorites;
};

let favs = handleFavorites('test.json');
console.log(favs);
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `initJson` does not use a Promise, therefore you can't await the response.
Revise `initJson` by returning a promise like the example included below.

```
function initJson(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
            resolve(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    });
};
```

Also converted `filterItemForKeyValue` for you:

```
var filterItemForKeyValue = function filterItemForKeyValue(object, key, value) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            if (typeof object !== 'undefined' && object) {
                resolve(object.filter(item => item[key] !== value));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            reject(false);
        }
    });
};
```

This is how you interact with the results after the changes supplied in the answer.

```
handleFavorites('test.json').then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Async functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Would I need to add a promise my array filter function as well?

Comment: @F.Rakes correct, let me know if you get stuck :) I've done a quick conversion for you above.

Comment: One more thing. When I try to return my final value it is wrapped around a Promise array ( `Promise { [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] }`) which I can't iterate over. Do I need to unwrap it first?

Comment: @F.Rakes Do you have an example on how you're returning the final value :)

Comment: Like the last two lines of my initial question. The objects inside are correctly read from the JSON file.

Comment: @F.Rakes See updated answer, you need to wait for the promise to resolve because the function is asynchronous now. :)

Comment: Thanks that does work :) Still somehow hard for me to wrap my head around asynchronous functions

Comment: @F.Rakes glad you've solved it. Think of it as you've assigned it to a variable but even if you execute it, it will just initiate the async function but not actually wait until it's returned. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your function `initJson` does not return its result as a promise, so you can't `await` it.

The core of that function is a call to `fs.readFile()`, which itself does not return a promise.  You can change that by using `util.promisify`, and your `initJson` function can return that as a promise.

On your filter function: it takes place on the call stack synchronously and does not involve asynchronous operations, so it does *not* need to wrapped in async or return a promise.  There's also no reason to assign it to a variable, especially not a global one.  Just use the function declaration, that's all you need.

Note the `doIt` function at the end wraps the calls to your async operations in the async keyword.  You could do this as a promise also, as in @Win 's answer.

Finally, I've modified my answer to show where you would handle errors in the call.  Depending on your needs, you might want to re-throw the error and catch it where you await the final result, that's up to you.

PS: I highly recommend checking out [this video on call stack vs event loop in JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ).  It's entertaining and will help you understand better why some calls are async and some are not.

```js
const {promisify} = require('util')
const fs = require('fs')
const readFileAsync = promisify(fs.readFile)

async function initJson(file) {
  const data = await readFileAsync(file, 'utf8')
  return JSON.parse(data)
}

function filterItemForKeyValue(object, key, value) {
  if (typeof object !== 'undefined' && object) {
    return object.filter(item => item[key] !== value)
  }
}

async function handleFavorites(file) {
  try {
    let favorites = await initJson(file)
    return await filterItemForKeyValue(favorites, 'delete', true)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('error', err.message)
  }
}

async function doIt(){
  const favorites = await handleFavorites('test.json')
  console.log(favorites)
}

doIt()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great as well, but I'll accept Win's answer for not having to require `promisify`.

Comment: No worries.  If you do decide to use it, it's part of the node standard library (version 8 and above I believe), so it does not require the installation of a separate package.

Comment: @F.Rakes one comment I would make is that it _might_ make sense to convert your code over to use _all_ promise based syntax, _or all_ async and await.  Just my opinion, but I think it makes the cognitive overhead a little lower to pick one path and go with it.

Comment: I initially tried to do it the async and await way since it looks a bit cleaner to me. Is there a way to catch errors if I `promisify` synchronous functions?

Comment: Do you mean how to handle an error with `fs.readFile` for example?  That call un-promisified is not synchronous, but rather passes its result to a callback handler, as you wrote it in your original question.  I will modify the answer to show error handling.